# How to access length of a list from another Class

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

In the app I am building I add names of people which you can see here in the peopleCheck property.
Now I want to make a new list which for each person will include a bool if he is here or not. (false is not here and vice versa)
I declared a new list "chk1" and what to fill it for every person as default false, and I want to make the overall list the same length as the peopleCheck list.
How can I do it?
I tried using "widget.peopleCheck.length()" but it returns two errors.
1. Only static members can be accessed in initializers.
2.The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PersonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> peopleCheck;
  PersonCheck({Key key, this.peopleCheck}) : super(key: key);
  //PersonCheck(this.peopleCheck);

  @override
  _PersonCheckState createState() => _PersonCheckState();
}

class _PersonCheckState extends State<PersonCheck> {

  List<bool> chk1 =List.filled(widget.peopleCheck.length(), false);




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'People Now',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: this.widget.peopleCheck.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, value) {
          return Card(
            color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
            elevation: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(value.toString()),
                title: Text(
                  widget.peopleCheck[value],
                ),
                trailing: Checkbox(
                  value: chk1[value],
                  onChanged: (bool val) {}, //(bool val) => setState(() => chk1[value] = val),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.check),
      ),
    );
  }
}
/*

 for (int i=0; i<widget.peopleCheck.length();i++){

  }



*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Length is a property of list so you can do this:

```
widget.peopleCheck.length
```

You're getting an error because length is not a function

You need to access to the widget in the build method, you can do this:

```
   List<bool> chk1;

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     chk1  = List.filled(widget.peopleCheck.length, false);

   }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still get an error that I cant use the widget. (Only static members can be accessed in initializers.)

Comment: Great, have a fantastic day.